# Getting "No current user" from aws-amplify and Cognito in react native

Tags: reactjs, amazon-web-services, react-native, amazon-cognito, aws-amplify

I am getting error saying "No current user" from `aws-amplify` if a user try to verify `email` after successful `Sign Up`.

I am trying to verify email and then fetch token from aws `Auth` to save in global state from `Auth.currentSession()`. And, this throws this error.

My Code:

```
import { Auth } from "aws-amplify";

try {
      setLoading(true);
await Auth.confirmSignUp(username, code); // email confirm
      
const token = (await Auth.currentSession())
        .getAccessToken()
        .getJwtToken();

}catch(err){
 console.log(err);  // error
}
```

`Error:  LOG  No current user`

Sometimes, I don't get this error.

Why I am getting this error? And How can I solve it?